# Firebase Push notification is not playing sound when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I've implemented Android Push Notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging FCM from [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) but the notification has not sound when application is in background.

Can anyone help me to set sound on firebase background notification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

make sure Sound is active like this

[image]

if deosn't work please check the official documentation 
[Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience?authuser=1)

Comment: Thank you. You Saved My Day!

Comment: Saved my day. +1

Comment: @MohammadHadi: You Know... unfortunately you need VPN to see the picture, if you are in Iran!