# Firebase Push notification is not playing sound when using cURL https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Tags: android, firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

When I use the Firebase console, everything is perfect by activating "Sound" under the "Advanced options" as explained by the best answer Mouad Abdelghafour AitAli wrote in the accepted answer at [Firebase Push notification is not playing sound when app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478311/firebase-push-notification-is-not-playing-sound-when-app-is-in-background). When I use cURL making the request to the endpoint `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`, I receive the notification and the only problem is that the notification does not play the sound. This is how I am sending the notification from the command prompt:

```
C:\curl>curl -k -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<My authorization key>" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"<Token of device that receives the notification>\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Yellow\"},\"priority\":10,\"sound\":\"default\"}"
{"multicast_id":4910170660116070247,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1512975815064180%efad4c69efad4c69"}]}
```

Notice how I am using `\"sound\":\"default\"`, but the notification is still not playing the sound. It works from the Firebase console as I mentioned, so I am trying to understand why it does not work using cURL from the command line. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46586285/7666442

Comment: @Nilu I already have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />` in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. I already enabled the sound option from the Firebase console when sending push notifications from the Firebase console but as I mentioned in my question, that works, but when I send the notification from the command prompt using cURL, the sound does not play. I am using the sound key in my the payload. I have already done what is suggested in the link you shared (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586215/android-notification-not-getting-sound-and-vibration/46586285#46586285).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the parameter `\"sound\":\"default\"` in the wrong place. I fixed it by using this the following code, and I received the notification with the default sound playing for this notification:

```
C:\curl>curl -k -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<My authorization key>" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"<My device token>\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Yellow\",\"sound\":\"default\"},\"priority\":10}"
{"multicast_id":6830402283642572741,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1512977917758257%efad4c69efad4c69"}]}
```